# Java NewIO: universal copy method (folder to folder, zip to folder, folder to zip, etc.) possible?

Tags: java, copy, universal

With Java NewIO it should be possible to have a single copy method that handles:

1. file (existing) to file
2. folder (and all its contents) to folder
3. zip to folder (a.k.a. extraction)
4. folder to zip (a.k.a. compression)
5. ...
6. ...

A jar/zip file is a filesystem just like my harddisk. Maybe one would need a little conditional execution in an universal copy method, but it should be possible, right? Maybe even with Filefilters and other stuff on top?

And if it is possible it should exist? I did some extensive Google search and got back nothing. There is a myriad of examples showing how to do one "type" of copy. But there is no universal copy method. Or is there? And if not, what would it look like?

Comment: You do know a "zip" is just a file? How would you copy a zip to a zip? A file to a file? How would your "universal copy" know which you intended?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It could probably be treated similar to a folder-to-folder copy, with the option to retain or overwrite existing contents, resulting in a merged zip in the destination.  To be fair, an API like this isn't the worst idea I've heard this week.

Comment: @NPras Apache Commons IO [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) has a lot of copy utilities, but I know of nothing that quite works like OP has described.

Comment: There are various copy-methods (copyFile, copyFolder, zip, unzip, etc.) but they all point to an universalCopy(enum copytype). Inside universalCopy need to be minimal difference conditionals depending on the enum argument...but since all is a FileSystem (HDD folders, zip, jar, etc.) those conditionals are very small.